# Strange Visual Studio message in the output window

Tags: visual-studio

I have some memory leaks in my project. I know that and I am going to fix them. The strange message I am referring to is the following (displayed in the output window of Visual Studio 10):

```
What were you thinking?
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
...
...
...
```

I have put the ... instead of the real memory dumping.

What on earth?!? Is it normal that Visual Studio writes: "What were you thinking?"? I didn't find any reference on the Internet to this. What could be?

Comment: I think it's pretty unlikely that this was actually generated by Visual Studio. Are you using any code written by others, any third-party tools or add-ins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a debugging output message from within your software, or a component you are referencing.

A common technique is to include a print (using Debug.WriteLine) within a finalizer on an object when building in Debug mode.  I would suggest searching for this text within your project(s).